# CannotOpen exception when trying to reopen same database

Tags: sqlite, mvvmcross

I'm trying to close a current SQLite connection and reopen a new one.
But sometimes, it's actually the same one (DB name is based on my user ID after login).

This fails with the below exception:

```
SQLite.SQLiteException occurred
  _HResult=-2146233088
  _message=Could not open database file: one.sql (CannotOpen)
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Could not open database file: one.sql (CannotOpen)
  Source=Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite.WindowsPhone
  StackTrace:
       at SQLite.SQLiteConnection..ctor(String databasePath, Boolean storeDateTimeAsTicks)
  InnerException:
```

To test, I've modified N-10-KittensDb, with the below code:

```
public DataService(ISQLiteConnectionFactory factory)
{
    using (_connection = factory.Create("one.sql"))
    {
        _connection.CreateTable<Kitten>();
    }

    using (_connection = factory.Create("one.sql"))
    {
        _connection.CreateTable<Kitten>();
    }
}
```

Why it would fail on the second using with above exception?

I've already tried calling Close(), Dispose() manually, settting connection var to null and calling `GC.Collect`, but nothing seems to fix this.
If I close the program and restart new, it works fine.
Looks like the file is in use or similar...

I've debugged until before the SQLlite3 code, and this line in the SQLiteConnection constructor:

```
var r = SQLite3.Open(DatabasePath, out handle);
```

is the one returning `CannotOpen`.

Any idea that could help me pass this, aside from closing the app?
 Closing the app could be a possibility, but looks like a to strong solution, as my user is just pressing the "log-out"  button.

Comment: Suspect this is wp community sqlite specific - see hits like http://wp7sqlite.codeplex.com/discussions/244820 - which suggests 
 `Community.CsharpSqlite.FileStream.HandleTracker.Clear();`

Comment: I switched to the Community plugin and the error does not reproduce anymore.
Thank you Stuart.